# Getmemorypool example?

Tags: development, json-rpc, raw-data, getmemorypool

I'm currently [trying to figure out](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=66300.0) how to properly use Getmemorypool for mining and I'm having some problems with it. Are there any examples provided somewhere on how to properly call that RPC with some data (for example showing a call with a block that ended up in the testnet block chain)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

First we call getmemory pool without arguments to get some data for our block:

```
{"method":"getmemorypool","params":[],"id":1}
```

bitcoind answers:

```
{
    "result": {
        "version":1,
        "previousblockhash":"0000000009a9a1c729d51337bf32ff300eeb59a5b3fbca99fc21c32e939c45f3",
        "transactions":["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","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"],
        "coinbasevalue":5000000000,
        "coinbaseflags":"062f503253482f",
        "time":1350579878,
        "mintime":1350577150,
        "curtime":1350579878,
        "bits":"1c2f36c0"
    },
    "error":null,
    "id":1
}
```

Next to create the block. We send:

```
{"method":"getmemorypool","params":["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"],"id":1}
```

bitcoind answers:

```
{"result":true,"error":null,"id":1}
```

What happens is that we use the data we get from the first RPC call to construct a block and then send a hex representation of that block to bitcoind. Going over every byte in the data above is a bit much to do here, but the big chunk of data that represents our block follows the bitcoin protocol binary layout for blocks, which can be found at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#block.

The block above exists at height 89819 of the testnet used by bitcoind 0.6. You may not be able to see it if you are on a different testnet.

Answer (score 2):

[Eloipool](http://gitorious.org/bitcoin/eloipool) (developed by the [Eligius mining pool](http://eligius.st))'s source code contains multiple examples of using getmemorypool. It also includes [a proof-of-concept proxy](http://gitorious.org/bitcoin/eloipool/blobs/master/gmp-proxy.py) for miners.